# Changing Key (PK, FK) properties in DROP/Add column statements

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, alter-table, ddl

I want to change a table by adding a column. So far nothing to see here, BUT I would like to make this column part of a composite key, i.e., I now have a layout

```
table_name( Field_1  datatype PK, Field_2 datatype,....)
```

and I want the inserted column, say Field_k to be part of a PK jointly with the existing single-field PK.

I haven't found any source for how to do this or for whether it is possible or not. Any advice, please?

Comment: You need to drop the FKs that reference it, then drop the PK and re-create it, then re-create the FK. There's no magic syntax for this.

Comment: Thanks, would I get a warning if I am (unknowingly, of course) violating some constraints in the process, i.e., if I forget to drop some referenced table? Just curious as to how SQL server handles integrity/constraint violations.

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to drop the PK while any FK still references it. And of course you won't be able to re-create the FK until those other tables also have a column that can fill in for the new column you're adding to the PK.

Comment: Excellent, do I write this as an answer (with due credit to you) or would you like to write it yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to drop the FKs that reference it, then drop the PK and re-create it, then re-create the FK. There's no magic syntax for this, but you can get some ideas here for how to generate the drop/create scripts for the FKs:

- [Why dropping all foreign keys from a script is not working?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77018/why-dropping-all-foreign-keys-from-a-script-is-not-working/)

> would I get a warning if I am (unknowingly, of course) violating some constraints in the process, i.e., if I forget to drop some referenced table? Just curious as to how SQL server handles integrity/constraint violations.

You won't be able to drop the PK while any FK still references it. And of course you won't be able to re-create the FK until those other tables also have a column that can fill in for the new column you're adding to the PK.